# PowerShell Receive-File dialog is empty

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm trying this really easy Receive-File but I'm getting a blanc popup.
I've tried different paths but always get the same result.

Another popup Read-Host is no problem. That one shows correctly.

I'm testing this out on a fresh 9.0.2 Azure web app with the PowerShell Module installed.

[image]

Anyone has a clue what I'm overlooking?

I don't have any JS errors. When looking and comparing the network calls, the PowerShellUploadFile2.aspx is returning a lot less than expected. 3 links instead of the full html document for the popup.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/default/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/sitecore/shell/controls/Lib/Flexie/flex.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Do you have any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Weirdly enough not. The response of PowerShellUploadFile2.aspx is not complete though.

Comment: Errors in the Sitecore logs?